# bash: ./<filename> No such file or directory

Tags: linker, binaryfiles, interpreter, glibc, loader

I'm trying to run a binary. But when I'm trying to run the file I'm facing the following error.

```
`pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ./house_of_force 
bash: ./house_of_force: No such file or directory`
```

```
`pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ldd ./house_of_force 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7c6da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3f879bd000)
    ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f87bf9000)
`
```

`

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ file ./house_of_force 
./house_of_force: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=278a2aec8b352ea120c49321ed3254eb15ca8ef5, with debug_info, not stripped`
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ readelf -l house_of_force 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400730
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x0000000000000027 0x0000000000000027  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000d88 0x0000000000000d88  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001d70 0x0000000000601d70 0x0000000000601d70
                 0x00000000000002c0 0x00000000000002c8  RW     0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000001d80 0x0000000000601d80 0x0000000000601d80
                 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000260 0x0000000000400260 0x0000000000400260
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000c04 0x0000000000400c04 0x0000000000400c04
                 0x000000000000004c 0x000000000000004c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000001d70 0x0000000000601d70 0x0000000000601d70
                 0x0000000000000290 0x0000000000000290  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

My System Details:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I've already done `chmod a+x house_of_force`
What I'm suspecting some shared object or the interpreter is broken.
I'm unable to link them properly.

Help me running the file properly using `./house_of_force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm facing the following error

The problem is that your binary is linked in a very weird way.

In particular, its interpreter is set to `../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2`, and this binary will run *only* when invoked from a directory in which `../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2` exists.

Invoking this binary from any other directory will fail with `ENOENT`.

It is unlikely that that's what you want this binary to do. You'll need to fix your link line -- usually the interpreter is set to the *absolute* path to `ld.so`.

P.S. You *probably* want to link with this custom GLIBC build in order to solve some problem. But it's unlikely that linking with custom GLIBC is the right solution to whatever that problem is. See http://xyproblem.info.

**Update:**

> It was a file given in linux heap exploitation course.

You should have explained this in your question.

Like the answer says, this binary will *only* run in a directory in which `../.glibc` exists. If you have `.glibc/` directory (containing `glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2`), then do this:

```
cd .glibc
mkdir foo
mv /path/to/house_of_force foo
cd foo
./house_of_force
```

Comment: `../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2`
I'm unable to figure out what this directory is. I've glibc and all the required files. 
But where should I put it
what is the interpretation of  `../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2`

Comment: @NobinPegasus What problem are you trying to solve by linking to the custom GLIBC?

Comment: I'm trying to to run the binary file.
I'm actually doing a course for that I need to run the binary.
In order to run it I need to link the interpreter.

Comment: It was a file given in linux heap exploitation course. House of Force. So I need to run the binary.

Comment: Okay I got my answer. Another thing is I've the glibc directory.
But what does the dot before the directory name mean?
should I just rename the the `glibc` directory to `.glibc`

Comment: After I've added the linker. Now it's broken 
It showed this at first

```pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ldd house_of_force  ./house_of_force: error while loading shared libraries: ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/libc.so.6: file too short
```

And finally it shows

```pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ./house_of_force 
bash: ./house_of_force: Input/output error
```
I've made `mv glibc .glibc` on the parent directory of the file I'm trying to execute

Comment: @NobinPegasus You have corrupted your `glibc` directory -- either you are out of space, or you copied files using FTP in `ASCII` mode, or something similar.

Comment: So suggest me a way to run the files.
I've my glibc directory. Should I download it again?
And how should I make in from `glibc` to `.glibc` so that it runs properly?
I'm stuck

Comment: @NobinPegasus The `mv glibc .glibc` command is fine and is the correct way to rename a directory. As for why your `glibc` is corrupt, you haven't said how or where you downloaded these binaries from. I suggest you accept this answer, and ask a new question with details of what exactly you did.